# is there a way to just view the playlist in youtube and not the videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I am looking at something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUNAiYO_LPY&list=PLqRhPbyFDQWg68lxH9Wf3nf0bkwpe9YnU . I hate it when the videos start to run and consume bandwidth and only want to see the playlists. Is there a way to only see the playlists and not run the video and consume the bandwidth. I am on metered connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit a URL like this

- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqRhPbyFDQWg68lxH9Wf3nf0bkwpe9YnU

Using the `https://www.youtube.com/playlist` instead of `https://www.youtube.com/watch` will show you the playlist.